# How to Offset Angular Application's URL

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular application which looks like this in terms of the directory structure

```
index.html
libs/
apps/
    feature1/
        directive.js
        view.html
    feature2/
    feature3/
```

The application runs in the root of the domain, i.e when you access http://localhost:8080/ the app loads. And other features are accessible in the following url scheme

```
http://localhost:8080/#/feature1
http://localhost:8080/#/feature2
http://localhost:8080/#/feature3
```

But now we are going for production setup (which I don't control much) and we also need a landing page. In the new scheme I want the application to load and run at http://production-domain.com/app. Please notice the "app" postfix. The root of the domain will serve only the landing page which will have no business with angular or the application itself. If will just have a link to http://production-domain.com/app. The new url scheme for features should look like this

```
http://production-domain.com/app/#/feature1
http://production-domain.com/app/#/feature2
http://production-domain.com/app/#/feature3
```

The application has a lot of view files (templateUrl stuff) and also lot of libs gets loaded through the index.html page. Essentially now the server will be running one level above compared to the current setup.

*What is the least intrusive (DRY) way of offsetting the whole angular app to any domain postfix. I don't want to the change the templateUrl path in all the directives.*

Answer (score 1):

To do what you are asking, you need to create a sub-folder in the root of your web server called "app". Then move the entire application in the sub-folder. That should be the end of it - meaning you do not have to do anything else and everything should work (given your assets use relative paths to the `index.html`, otherwise you have to change those).

Comment: let me try this.

Comment: No, it doesn't ! All the templateUrl path in the directives are relative to the server, hence they need to change.

Comment: They should not ne in the first place. But if they are, just change them. Does not seem like a big issue...

Comment: It wasn't that easier either :-) . My code base is more than 30K lines of angular code. And there were no less than 25 directives. Eventually I did things the hard way !

Comment: I imagine it should be simple using a regex replace. But maybe not. Anyway, glad my answer helped you.